# How does Maple compute this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

After multiple steps into a problem, I arrived at the integral

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}\mathrm{d}t.$$

Here the primitive can be easily calculated by posing $x=\arctan u$ and $\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{u^2+1}\mathrm{d}u$. We obtain that

$$\int\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}\mathrm{d}t=5\arctan\frac{5}{4}\tan t.$$

If the integration domain is applied to the primitive, I get

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}\mathrm{d}t=5\arctan\frac{5}{4}\tan 2\pi-5\arctan\frac{5}{4}\tan 0=0.$$

By looking at the graph of $\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}$, clearly the area under the curve in $[0,2\pi]$ isn't zero. This function is always positive and never crosses the x-axis. If I plug the initial integral directly into Maple, it gives me that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}\mathrm{d}t=10\pi,$$

which is the expected answer in my problem. Now, I'm not sure what's wrong with the integral. As far as I can understand it, the integral is not Riemann integrable (correct me if I'm wrong), thus

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}\mathrm{d}t\neq 5\arctan\frac{5}{4}\tan 2\pi-5\arctan\frac{5}{4}\tan 0.$$

My question is the following, how does Maple compute this integral? Or in a more general sense, what to do when the integral isn't Riemann integrable? Which part of calculus did I break?

Comment: Try to split your integral as 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}\mathrm{d}t+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}\mathrm{d}t+\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}\mathrm{d}t+\int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}\frac{100}{16+9\sin^2t}\mathrm{d}t
$$
and apply your reasoning to each of these four integrals...

Comment: Is it the boundaries that you are mixing? Notice that arctan gives a range of $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. So break the integral into 4 times from 0 to $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Gabriel. There is an important lesson to learn here why you arrive at zero, and it is because of the nature of your substitution. Because $x=arctanu$ implies $tanx=u$ and since you are integrating from 0 to 2pi, your u-sub poses discontinuities and that....is not allowed! For that reason you must split u the integral at pi/2, as suggested by others and proceed from there using symmetry of the graph

Comment: Oh wow, that didn't come to my mind. That makes a lot of sens now. Thanks a lot!